# Classify / section line or group of points according to shape (with shapely objects)

Tags: python, classification, shapely, correlation, pysal

Is there any python module/function that classifies/sections a shapely line according to the shape the line forms?

If not, I could do it with the positions of the points that form the line. I would like to ignore the absolute coordinates of the points, and classify according to the **relative positions** between them (in batches or something). Is there any mathematical coefficient that analyses this in particular? Or the correlation between points but without being the absolute coordinates?

I have searched ways but I don't find any solution. The closest thing I have come to is PySAL, but from what I understood, it serves for the correlation/classification of **OTHER** fields (like population, income...) using the coordinates to group them.

**UPDATED**

As an example, I have the following LineString (shapely object). I can generate any number of points along the line.
[image]

Comment: I have uploaded the image just now. I do not really need a precise classification, it could be more like some generic shapes. First part circle and line, in the middle 2-4 shapes and the final line.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include an example of the intended output?